# Examining the Win Probability of a Particular Play-style in a Set of Tournaments

Tags: logistic, random-effects-model

Something I've been playing around with in my head, which I'd like some advice on. Assume you have a game with four different "play-styles" - this can be a particular strategy, different team compositions, etc. There is a series of tournaments with a variable number of players (and no fixed set of players) that you have results from, and you'd like to figure out the probability of a win, or at least a decent placing, for each play style to see if they are well balanced. So for an example data set:

```
Style Place Tournament
A 1 1
B 2 1
A 3 1
C 4 1
B 5 1
D 6 1
A 7 1
C 8 1
B 1 2
D 2 2
C 3 2
A 4 2
D 1 3
C 2 3
B 3 3
A 4 3
D 5 3
C 6 3
B 7 3
```

I've been considering using a logistic regression model with a new 0/1 variable for a "Top 5" placing - or it could equally be for the winner, and then using a model where the tournament is a random effect and the style is a fixed effect. But I am, admittedly, not terribly familiar with this type of problem, so I'd be interested to hear if people have other ideas or approaches that might work better.

Comment: It would help to have better data. The results you show could be severely interdependent, depending on whether the same subgroups of players are showing up in tournaments and on the tournament structures themselves. Couldn't you collect data about *individuals*, their styles, and their head-to-head results? You could then conceivably conduct a standard analysis of playing strength, including playing styles (and their interactions) as covariates. One is still left wondering how you could separate "style" from "skill" unless some individuals use multiple styles.

Comment: @whuber I don't actually have control over how the data are collected. I *may* be able to collect data about individuals - but honestly, I know nothing about "a standard analysis of playing strength" so if you wanted to go into that further I'd be grateful. And yes, there is a valid question as to whether style can be separated from skill, but lets assume it's a necessary abstraction (or alternately, that any skilled player can pick any style and play reliably).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't care to go into standard analyses because I think you would be better off consulting [other threads where they are discussed](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=strength+play).

Comment: @whuber Only one of the links in that search seems to be directly relevant, where there is but one answer.

Comment: I agree that not all the hits in that search are relevant. But I find about half of those threads deal directly with models of the strength of play or to predict outcomes in contests. When you need answers, it helps to see how situations that are not exactly the same as yours nevertheless are closely related in terms of data and objectives, for then you will obtain much more information and insight. If you're still having trouble, then by all means expand the search with additional terms: there's plenty of information out there.

Comment: A different [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bradley+terry) related to one approach